# Can I still use SDLfilter after the retirement of maptools?

Tags: r, gps, spatial

I am working on animal tracking data and I wanted to use SDLfilter to clean the data. However, since the retirement of maptools, when I try to load SDLfilter I get the following:

```
> library(SDLfilter)
Error: package or namespace load failed for ‘SDLfilter’ in loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]):
 there is no package called ‘maptools’
```

Do you know if there are other ways to use SDLfilter? If not, do you know of similar packages for cleaning GPS tracking data (track2kba, trip, etc.)?

Thanks in advance. Sorry if my question seems newbish, it's the first time I work with such data.

Cheers!

I tried loading "SDLfilter" but it seems I need "maptools" first.

Comment: Hi Ioannis, today is your lucky day - you have chosen to install a package whose dependencies have been removed CRAN literally today. You'll have to go to the CRAN archive for each package you'll need (not just maptools, but ggsn, and likely others), download them and install them manually. Here is the archive repository for maptools: https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/maptools/ The other packages will have a similar URL logic.